# Neniu postlasota ino!

Tags: phrase-requests

Hodiaŭ en multaj landoj inoj manifestacias sub la devizo “No woman left behind”, “Ni una menos”, ks. Ĉu iu havas pli bonan tradukon, ol tiu, kiun mi proponas en la demandotitolo?

***Redakto:*** estas jam tempo konkludi ion pri tiu ĉi demando. Unue mi klarigu, kiel mi alvenis al la titola propono. La laŭvorta traduko de la originala hispana estas ***eĉ ne unu ino malpli,*** sed tio sonas al mi kiel langorompaĵo, same kiel la iom pli bona ***neniu ino malpli.*** En tiu kunteksto simpla ***ino*** ŝajnas al mi pli bona ol ***virino,*** kaj mi enŝovis participon por distancigi la ***-n-*** de ***ino*** disde la ***-n-*** de ***eĉ ne*** aŭ ***neniu.***  Tio estis preskaŭ laŭvorta traduko de la angla versio kaj tio kontentigis min.

Tamen la respondo de Kirilo klarigas, ke tiu participo (same kiel, mi supozas, la eventuala adverbo ***malpli***) povas esti nekomprenebla eĉ al akademiano.

Mi konfesas, ke la unuan fojon, kiam mi vidis insignon ***Esperanto parolata,*** ankaŭ mi taksis ĝin nekomprenebla kaj multe malpli bona ol ***Oni parolas Esperanton.*** Tio signifas, ke, malgraŭ onia fojfoja emo uzi ĝin, memstara participo en Esperanto ne sufiĉas por senhezite sugesti subkomprenatan ĉefverbon. El tio sekvas, ke anglalingvaj gazet-titoloj kaj frapfrazoj ne povas esti modelo per ties Esperantaj tradukoj.

Tial mi akceptis la respondon de Kirilo, kvankam je tiu ĉi punkto mi opinias ***ni postlasu*** pli bona ol simpla infinitivo, kaj mi devos alkutimiĝi al la langotordaĵo. Kaj, intertempe, mi ekpreferis la verbon ***neglekti***. ***Ni neglektu neniun inon***, do.

Comment: Evidente vi trovis la plej bonan tradukon, ĉar neniu respondas! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi devis legi la anglan esprimon por kompreni, kion celas la Esperanta.
Mi esprimus ĝin aktive: "Neniun virinon postlasi!" Aŭ se mi rajtas esprimi ĝin pli libere, pli klare: "Ne marĝenigi ajnan virinon!"

Comment: Dankon, Kirilo, por la respondo, kiun mi komentis en la rekdaktita parto de la demando. Mi akceptas ĝin, kvankam mia preferata fina vortumo estas ankoraŭ tute alia. Kompreneble, ĉiu rajtas esprimi sin tiel libere, kiel tiu volas...

Comment: Jes, _neglekti_ estas ankoraŭ pli bona solvo.